# Run-time error for a simple code

Tags: c++

I am new to coding and this is a simple program I wrote to accept no of test cases and for each case display a text if it satisfies conditions or a -1 if it doesn't.However, I keep encountering run-time ever when I try to upload it in the CodeChef Website. Please do advise.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int T,sol_arr[10],i;

      //  cout<<"Enter the number of test cases\n";
        cin>>T;

    if(T>=1||T<=1000)
    {
        for(i=1;i<=T;i++)
        {
           // cout<<"\nEnter value for test case number -\t"<<i<<"\n";
           cin>>sol_arr[i-1];
        }

        for(i=1;i<=T;i++)
        {
            if(sol_arr[i-1]>=-20 && sol_arr[i-1]<=20)
                cout<<"What an obedient Servant you are !\n";
            else
                cout<<"-1\n";
        }
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Imagine `T` has the value of 11.

Answer (score 1):

```
cin>>sol_arr[i-1];
```

can cause *buffer overflow* as you declared

```
int sol_arr[10];
```

and `i` can be `1` to `1000`.

Create `sol_arr` such way so that it can contain at least `1000` value, e.g.

```
int sol_arr[1000];
```

but don't forget, C++ arrays are zero indexed.